# Want to have my wordpress blog in a subfolder instead of root; getting 403 error(obviously). How can I fix this?

Tags: wordpress

So yeah, just installed wordpress not too long ago, I set everything up and got up to the dashboard. I made a test post and I got a 403 error. I also clicked the top of my dashboard which should take me to the main page of my wordpress blog and it failed as well. This isn't really surprising since my wordpress is in the folder blog of my root directory, and so my main page of my wordpress blog is also a folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress Codex should have any answer you are looking for:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Be sure the check the "WordPress address (URL)" in the General Settings in your wordpress admin. And also update your Permalinks, by going to the Permalinks tab and simply hit Save Changes